# How can the inset shadow be removed from button and .button elements when using Foundation?

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation with Sass and have been unable remove the inset shadow from `<button>` and `.button` elements.

Things I've tried include:

- Looking for a foundation override to set (none exists, verified by looking at their code)
- Explicitly setting `+inset-shadow(false)` on `button, .button` in my own sass, to no avail

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some more specific googling and was able to find a suggestion that worked here (https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/2297).

Setting `box-shadow: none` rather than using the Foundation `+inset-shadow` mixin works. In my case, I'm actually using Compass's `+box-shadow(none)`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try +inset-shadow(none) ?

You can also remove the following line from your scss file
https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/components/_buttons.scss#L207

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but `+inset-shadow(none)` doesn't work, and I'd really like to avoid mucking around in the Foundation code if possible as this needs to work on multiple machines and I don't want to deal with that when upgrading. It seems crazy to me that there isn't an easy & obvious way to do this :-(.